# How to pass an object as value in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is it allowed to pass an object (like a tree) as the output value of a mapper in Hadoop? Is so, how?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877077/how-do-i-set-an-object-as-the-value-for-map-output-in-hadoop-mapreduce/13877688#13877688

Comment: Thanks. But how should I override the readFields and writeFields? Is is necessary?

Comment: write is for serializing the fields of object (tree in your case) to the output stream and read is used to deserialized the fields of the object from the input stream. for a detailed info you can go to: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Writable.html

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Tariq's links, and to simply detail one possible implementation for a `<Text, IntWritable>` treemap:

```
public class TreeMapWritable extends TreeMap<Text, IntWritable> 
                             implements Writable {

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        // write out the number of entries
        out.writeInt(size());
        // output each entry pair
        for (Map.Entry<Text, IntWritable> entry : entrySet()) {
            entry.getKey().write(out);
            entry.getValue().write(out);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        // clear current contents - hadoop re-uses objects
        // between calls to your map / reduce methods
        clear();

        // read how many items to expect
        int count = in.readInt();
        // deserialize a key and value pair, insert into map
        while (count-- > 0) {
            Text key = new Text();
            key.readFields(in);

            IntWritable value = new IntWritable();
            value.readFields(in);

            put(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically the default serialization factory in Hadoop expects objects output to implement the Writable interface (the readFields and write methods detailed above). In this way you can pretty much extend any class to retro-fit the serialization methods.

Another option is to enable Java Serialization (which uses default java serialization methods) `org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.JavaSerialization` by configuring the `io.serializations` configuration property, but i wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
Let's assume that the class that I'd like to serialize has two variables, one of type ArrayList and one of type int. Could you help me through overriding the readFields and write function?