# How Java Hadoop Mapper can send multiple values

Tags: java, hadoop, mapper

My mapper needs to send the following tuples:

```
<custID,prodID,rate>
```

And I want to send to reducer the custID as a key, and as value the prodID and rate together, as they are needed for the reduce phase.
Which is the best way of doing this?

```
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) 
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String[] col = value.toString().split(",");
    custID.set(col[0]);
    data.set(col[1] + "," + col[2]);
    context.write(custID, data);
}

public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    for (Text val : values) {
        String[] temp = val.toString().split(",");
        Text rate = new Text(temp[1]);
        result.set(rate);
        context.write(key, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just send multiple values? Nothing limits the number of key-value pairs a single map task can produce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest I can think of is just to merge them into a single string:

```
output.collect(custID, prodID + "," + rate);
```

Then, split if back up on the reducers.

If you post a little more code from your mapper maybe we could give a better example.

UPDATE: That said, you asked for the *best* way. The most correct way is probably to create a separate class grouping `prodID` and `rate` together and send that.

Comment: I try this solution (to merge them), but when in reducer I use String v = val.toString().split(","); command to split the string, I can use the v[0] regularly, but when I use v[1] value I get an exception "array out of bounds".

Comment: Can you post some code (into your original question, or a pastebin / github gist) for what you currently have?

Comment: you might find this useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877077/how-do-i-set-an-object-as-the-value-for-map-output-in-hadoop-mapreduce/13877688#13877688

Comment: This is not really the recommended way of doing it as it will be less efficient, passing the prodID and rate around as strings. It also requires string manipulation in the reducer which is another inefficiency.

Answer (score 14):

The best way is to write CustomWritables

This is for double value. You can change that to Text or String

```
import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;


/**
 * @author Unmesha SreeVeni U.B
 *
 */
public class TwovalueWritable implements Writable {
    private double first;
    private double second;

    public  TwovalueWritable() {
        set(first, second);
    }
    public  TwovalueWritable(double first, double second) {
        set(first, second);
    }
    public void set(double first, double second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
    public double getFirst() {
        return first;
    }
    public double getSecond() {
        return second;
    }
    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeDouble(first);
        out.writeDouble(second);
    }
    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        first = in.readDouble();
        second = in.readDouble();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        long temp;
        temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(first);
        result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
        temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(second);
        result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
        return result;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof TwovalueWritable)) {
            return false;
        }
        TwovalueWritable other = (TwovalueWritable) obj;
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(first) != Double
                .doubleToLongBits(other.first)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (Double.doubleToLongBits(second) != Double
                .doubleToLongBits(other.second)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return first + "," + second;
    }
}
```

And from mapper you can just emit it as

```
context.write(key,new TwovalueWritable(prodID,rate));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @RaviHTapela: If you are using Eclipse IDE - equals,hashCode can be generated automatically