# How to output intermediate key/value pairs, where multiples values are associated with a single key in a map program?

Tags: java, mapreduce

I am working on the implementation of page rank algorithm, where the map program should write

```
Key=outlink value=sourcepage,final pagerank value
```

where the input is of the format

```
source page outlinks inital pagerank value of the source page
```

Example:

Input to Map Program:

```
X AB 0.25
```

Output of Map Program:

```
key = A value= X 0.125
key = B value= X 0.125
```

I used the `context.write(Text,Text)` method to output the key value pair.

The value is combination of char and a double value which I converted to `String` and passed as the `Text` object to `context.write`.

```
finalValue = Character.toString(sourcePage)+","+String.valueOf(finalpr);

context.write(new Text(Character.toString(page1)), new Text(finalValue));
```

Is there a better way to pass multiple values for a key? Please provide insights.

Comment: Does this similar question help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734154/how-java-hadoop-mapper-can-send-multiple-values

Comment: @Jeremy Yes, I got an idea. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could just write the entire output as a Text key value and a NullWritable value.  Then once you are working with the output data you could just use the Java split function to divide it up by delimiters.  So do something like

new Text("key = A::value= X::0.125")

Then once you're processing it somewhere else you can just do String [] results = key.split("::");

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Doing this will cause the reducer to run `reduce()` for every value instead of for every key.